# celery tasks queue not working with rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Celery tasks successfully executing without queues

setup.

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672/test"
# Celery Data Format
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

@app.task
def test(a,b,c):
    print("doing something here...")
```

command

```
celery worker -A proj -E -l INFO
```

The above setup worker is executing successfully.

I have introduced queue to the celery tasks.

added configuration with the previous setup

```
from kombu.entity import Exchange, Queue

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('high', Exchange('high'), routing_key='high'),
    Queue('normal', Exchange('normal'), routing_key='normal'),
    Queue('low', Exchange('low'), routing_key='low'),
)

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'normal'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'normal'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'normal'

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'myapp.tasks.test': {'queue': 'high'},
}
```

command

```
celery worker -A proj -E -l INFO -n worker.high -Q high
```

call

```
 test.delay(1, 2, 3)
```

When I execute with the queue worker is not running. Did I miss any configuration?

Comment: Any info inside rabbit and celery logs?

Comment: I didnt add any celery logs. I will add it. Do I need to configure queue names on rabbitmq for celery ?

Comment: You dont have to do anything on rabbit, just make sure rabbit is running and listening on that port and interface, if you are on a linux machine and have access to a shell run netstat -putan | grep 5672

Comment: yes running and listening.

Comment: it worked when I add @app.task(queue='high').

Comment: ahh yes, ofc, you have to specify the queue in the decorator if you are using an specific queue :P

Comment: CELERY_ROUTES - also same config. but don't know why that is not working.

Comment: @RoshanA did u see my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CELERY_ROUTES to CELERY_TASK_ROUTES- changed in version 4

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that connection established in both rabbit & high worker logs.

Then, try to change your `CELERY_ROUTES` to:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'myapp.tasks.test': {
        'exchange': 'high',
        'exchange_type': 'high',
        'routing_key': 'high'
    }
}
```

or call the task with `queue`, for example:

```
test_task = test.signature(args=(1, 2, 3), queue='high', immutable=True)
test_task.apply_async()
```